# How to get select value text with Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, select

How can I get select option with Laravel? Not Select value just Text.

For example;

```
<select name="assignedUser">
    <option value="123">John</option>
</select>
```

I want to take the name John. Because the user needs the name and ID.

```
$request->input('assigned')->text() like this
```

I hope, You understand me... Can you help me ? Thank you.

Comment: Where do you need this text ? I mean at server side(After submits the form)  or client side(Ex :Onchange, onload page.. ) ?

Comment: I need to send id and name when sending with api. @iamatstackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

*You can also refer this example*

```
$selectionOptions = [1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'C'];
$selected = $selectionOptions[$request->input('selection-list')];
```

**Or you can just update the HTML to have the text as the value**

```
<select name="selection-list">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't like this job. It shouldn't be that hard. Thank you.